# Diagonal Direction Edge Detection

Tags: image-processing

Let say that a given image has an edge in some angle (not neglectable), so we use edge detection mask rotated, for example sobel operator in 45 degrees:

```
 0  1  2 
-1  0  1
-2 -1  0
```

or

```
-2 -1  0 
-1  0  1 
 0  1  2
```

In this case, how we will find the magnitude of the edge?

Comment: The vertical and horizontal sobel kernels can be used to determine magnitude. The magnitude from a single kernel is just the output value of the kernel. Think about doing a horizontal Sobel, then trying to calculate the magnitude. The magnitude will be the output value.

Comment: @BHawk so how does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirsch_operator work?

Comment: It rotates an edge kernel, which is different than the Sobel kernel. It then uses the maximum value of all of the 8 magnitudes as the output. Sobel provides Euclidean vector style magnitude (x versus y strength). Kirsch provides whatever the max is in any direction.

Comment: Sobel is almost rotation invariant. Other filters are better at rotation invariance, but the error in Sobel is likely good enough for you. Just compute the magnitude, it will be correct for edges at any orientation.

Comment: Sobel method provides a directional vector, kirsch provides only a magnitude.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Kirsch operator is first order derivative as sobel? as unlike any other first order operator that I seen it matrix degree is 2, just like the laplacian (which is second order)

Comment: Kirsch is a weird operator. Yes, each of the 8 kernels are intended to approximate first order derivatives. The complete operator returns the maximum response over the 8 kernels, and so is comparable to the gradient magnitude. But it's not going to be nearly as precise as the gradient magnitude computed through Sobel.